# Suppose that $E[X^2Y^2] <\infty$. Can we conclude that $E[X^2]<\infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose that $E[X^2Y^2] <\infty$. Can we conclude that $E[X^2]<\infty$, $E[Y^2]<\infty$  $E[|X|]<\infty$, $E[|Y|]<\infty$?

Attempt: If $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are uncorrelated, then $E[X^2Y^2]=E[X^2]E[Y^2]<\infty$ which implies $E[X^2]<\infty$ and  $E[Y^2]<\infty$. One can conclude $E[X]<\infty$ and  $E[Y]<\infty$ then $E[|X|]<\infty$, $E[|Y|]<\infty$.

Are there any other assumptions that will allow me to conclude all the implications.?

Comment: Let $Y$ be a random variable that always takes the value $0$...

Comment: How will that guarantee $E[X^2]<\infty$?

Comment: It is a counterexample to your proposition: obviously you _can't_ conclude that $E[X^2]<\infty$ in this case, even though $E[X^2Y^2]=0$.

Comment: Oh. That makes Sense.

Comment: However the provided counterexample doesn't show that $E(X^2 Y^2) < \infty$ implies one of $E(X^2) < \infty$ and $E(Y^2)  < \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample to *all* the claims: let $X, Y$ be defined on the common probability space $\Omega = [0, 1]$ (and Lebesgue measure) such that
$$\begin{align*}
X(\omega) &= \begin{cases}
  1/ \omega, &0 < \omega < 1/2 \\
  0, & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases} \\
  Y(\omega) &= \begin{cases}
  1/ (1-\omega), &1/2 < \omega < 1 \\
  0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
Note that $XY(\omega) = 0$ for all $\omega$, but that $X, Y$ each have infinite expectation individually.

What makes this example work is that these variables are highly **dependent** on one another....

Comment: Did you intend $Y(\omega)$ insteaad of $f_{Y(\omega)}$?

Comment: @NoeVidales Yes, of course -- thanks for the catch!